# How to compile C++ code using modules-ts and gcc (experimental)?

Tags: gcc, g++

I've been trying to code something using the new experimental feature "modules-ts" that will be included in c++20. I've cloned the gcc branch (found here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules), and I'm trying to follow that tutorial (on the link) using modules-ts but an g++ error is preventing me from doing that:

> g++: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-fmodules-ts’

I tried to see the version of g++, to make sure that is not reading from another previous version. And the answer is:

> g++ (GCC) 10.0.0 20191029 (experimental)
>   Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Here is the command that I'm trying to run:

> g++ -fmodules-ts hello.cppm main.cpp

Answer (score 5):

Modules-ts is not merged into GCC's main branch yet. You need to download GCC's source and compile it yourself, for further instructions see [GCC's installation guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/). Grab the source using

```
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/c++-modules SomeLocalDir
```

instead of

```
svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk SomeLocalDir
```

and you'll get the correct version.

EDIT:
For clarification, in this answer I assumed the OP did not compile the right GCC version because there is no svn revision number inside his gcc --version.