# error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, module, g++, c++20

I've just purchased the book Beginning C++20 (the eBook version) and I'm trying to compile the first example using the new C++20 method.

The content of the source file is

```
// Ex1_01.cpp
// A Complete C++ program
import <iostream>;

int main()
{
    int answer{42};     // Defines answer with 42
    std::cout << "The answer to life, the universe, and everything is "
        << answer
        << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I understand correctly this is not yet supported by GCC version 10 or 11 (some sites claim that GCC 11 support it, but when I use the -fmodules-ts flag as some suggest there is an error message that it's not implemented/experimental and quits.

After some searching I've found some posts refering to https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules where there are instructions to install a version of GCC 10 with support for modules (using the -fmodules-ts flag) but when I use that on my example code I get the following error:

```
In module imported at Ex1_01.cpp:3:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/10.0.0/iostream: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
/usr/local/include/c++/10.0.0/iostream: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/./usr/local/include/c++/10.0.0/iostream.gcm’
/usr/local/include/c++/10.0.0/iostream: fatal error: jumping off the crazy train to crashville
compilation terminated.
```

The version of gcc is:
g++ (GCC) 10.0.0 20200110 (experimental) [svn-280157:20201220-1704]
I found a post here on Stack Overflow where someone points to this version ([How to compile C++ code using modules-ts and gcc (experimental)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712244/how-to-compile-c-code-using-modules-ts-and-gcc-experimental))

I also tried the examples from the wiki (hello.cc and main.cc) but those also give an error message:

```
In module imported at main.cpp:1:1:
hello: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
hello: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/hello.gcm’
hello: fatal error: jumping off the crazy train to crashville
compilation terminated.
```

Is there a way to make this work, or should I just start with the "old" #include method until there is a stable release of GCC 11 with support for modules? As I understand if I build the latest snapshot of GCC 11 most other C++20 specific code should work? (or just stick with the default (g++ (Debian 10.2.1-1) 10.2.1 20201207) version supplied by my distribution?)

Comment: If you are trying to learn about modules, you are stuffed. If you are new-comer trying to learn some C++, then a practical approach to continuing with your learning is to switch back to the old include syntax `include <iostream>` :)

Comment: I'm a new-commer trying to learn C++, I figured since the import <iostream>; method is considered a "better" solution compated to the #include <iostream> method. I might as well start using the newer/better way to do this.

But I guess I'll just have to use the #include method for now.

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I agree completely but I've only seen working implementations of modules with the MSVC compiler. You may have to wait a while before it is implemented in either GCC or Clang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess I'll be answering my own question.

When I follow the instructions on the GCC wiki (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules) it's a newer version compared to the one found on svn.

The svn has a version 10 of gcc while github has version 11.

When I compile the version for github (g++ (GCC) 11.0.0 20201217 (experimental) [c++-modules revision 20201220-2203]) the examples provided by the GCC Wiki compile and work. These files are
hello.cpp:

```
module;
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
export module hello;
export void greeter (std::string_view const &name)
{
  std::cout << "Hello " << name << "!\n";
}
```

and main.cpp

```
import hello;
int main (void)
{
  greeter ("world");
  return 0;
}
```

The command to compile is: g++ -fmodules-ts hello.cpp main.cpp

As I understand the order of the sourcefiles is important so hello.cpp needs to be compiled before main.cpp

So at the moment it seems that only user-made modules work, but not the Standard library ones (for those #include is still required).

[edit]
It seems that the modules support is now merged with the main branch of gcc-11 so using the developer builds through git or svn are no longer required (unfortunately the standard library headers like  are not converted into modules yet, so at the moment import ; doesn't work).

Comment: You can convert std_lib headers to modules with `g++ -c -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header  -std=c++20 iostream string vector`

Comment: How to build the module and the code which uses the module separately?

Comment: @debashish.ghosh - Presumably you mean "How do I have a separate interface and implementation when writing my own module?". The answer is interesting. In the interface file you say `export module foo;` and then have export statements for each name you want the module to provide to others.   In the implementation you say `module foo;` instead. You cannot have any export statements in the implementation file.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! It works on CMake 3.18.4. As stated in the solution above, make sure the sources that are (user-defined) modules are FIRST when listing them in your ${SOURCES} variable. And don't forget to add `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fmodules-ts")` to your CMakeList.txt ;) Again, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For the following code on Linux Ubuntu 20.04

```
import <iostream>;
import <limits>;

int main()
{
    int min{ std::numeric_limits<int>::max()};
    int max{ std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
    bool any { false };
    int x;

    while(std::cin >> x)
    {
        any = true;
        if(x < min)
            min = x;
        if(x> max)
            max = x;
    }

    if(any)
        std::cout<<"min = "<<min<<"\nmax = "<<max<<'\n';
}
```

I had to install `g++-11` then

```
g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header iostream
g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header limits
g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts list0201.cpp -o list0201
$ ./list0201
10
20
-100 
ctrl+D
```

```
min = -100
max = 20
```

Answer (score 2):

I've built `// Ex1_01.cpp` the source file from the question by two commands:

```
$ g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header iostream
$ g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -o Ex1_01 Ex1_01.cpp
```

After running `Ex1_01`, I've got:

```
The answer to life, the universe, and everything is 42
```